# Package installation issue - arabi

Tags: packages, installing

I am very new to Latex and I have a file I need to compile.
When doing so I get the message: The required file tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg is missing. It is a part of the following package: arabi".

I hit install and install the package. However, the next time I compile the file I get the same message over and over.

What is the issue?

I also attached message screenshot[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe the installation failed for some reason. It sems you're under MiKTeX?. Try installing the package via MiKTeX Package Manager, as administrator. With MPM, you'll see whether it was installed anyway.